How do you Update a Variable in your Flask Template without Javascript?
I am trying to make a Library Management Project Using Flask, with a search functionality for the books.
Reference Image
If I type something into the search box, i want to see only those books.
Here is my HTML
{% block content %}
<div class="search-area">
    <div class="input">
        <input class="search" type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Search A Book" autocomplete="off">
        <img src="static/icons/search.svg">
    </div>
</div>

<main id="main-content">
    {% if search_term %}
      {% for book in books %}
        <div class="container">
          <div class="inner-containers" id="{{book['ID']}}" onclick="showReader('{{book['ID']}}')">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img draggable="false" class="book-image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='thumbnails/' + book['Image']) }}">
            </div>
            <div class="book-details">
              <p class="name">{{ book['Name'] }}</p>
              <p class="author">{{ book['Author'] }}</p>
              <p class="details">{{ book['Date'] }} &#183; {{ book['Genre'] }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {% for book in original_books %}
        <div class="container">
          <div class="inner-containers" id="{{book['ID']}}" onclick="showReader('{{book['ID']}}')">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img draggable="false" class="book-image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='thumbnails/' + book['Image']) }}">
            </div>
            <div class="book-details">
              <p class="name">{{ book['Name'] }}</p>
              <p class="author">{{ book['Author'] }}</p>
              <p class="details">{{ book['Date'] }} &#183; {{ book['Genre'] }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    
    <p class="section-title">This Month in Horror</p>
  </main>

{% endblock %}

I made a Python Function to handle the input
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
  books = books_df.books.to_dict('records')
  original_books = books.copy()  # Assuming you want a copy for full data
  search_term = ''  # Initialize empty search term

  if request.method == 'POST':
    # Handle search term
    data = request.get_json()
    search_term = data.get('searchTerm', '').lower()  # Get and lowercase search term

    # Filter books based on search term (if provided)
    if search_term:
      filtered_books = books_df.books[books_df.books['Name'].str.lower().str.contains(search_term)]
      books = filtered_books.to_dict('records')
      print(books)
    return render_template('home.html', books=books, search_term = search_term)  # Pass both variables
  return render_template('home.html', original_books=original_books, search_term = None)

and Here's the JS to send it over to python
<script>
        inputbox = document.getElementById('search-box');

        inputbox.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        let input = inputbox.value.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (input.length) {
            // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/home"); // Replace with your actual endpoint

            // Set request headers (optional, but recommended for data format)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Send the search term as JSON data
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: input }));
        }
    })
        
    </script>

The JS and Python are both Working as Intended, but when i search nothing happens. Here  is the whole code. Thanks.

maybe use alert() or console.log() in JavaScript and print() in Python to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. You could also use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see errors in JavaScript (and messages fromconsole.log())

when you use JavaScript (XMLHttpRequest or fetch) to send message to server then you have to get response and replace it in browsers - browser will NOT update it automatically. This way you can get only parts of data (instead of full HTML) and replace only some elements on page.

if you generate full HTML to replace full page then maybe don't use JavaScript but normal <form method="POST"> with <button> - and this will automatically update page when you press button.

@furas Is it possible to trigger form submission every time i type something?

it needs to use JavaScript. But it would be better to get result from XMLHttpRequest and replace part of HTML in browser. Frankly, I would use modern fetch(url, ...).then(response => response.text).then(...function_which_replace_html...) and use some_item.innerHTML = new_html

When you use XMLHttpRequest or fetch then you have to replace HTML on your own - browse will NOT replace it automatically. It allows to replace only part of HTML instead of full page.
outputbox.innerHTML = new_HTML;

For example using fetch
        fetch("/search", {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify({searchTerm: input})
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {outputbox.innerHTML = text;});


Minimal working code:
I use modern fetch instead of old XMLHttpRequest
I also use render_template_string to put all code in one file - this way everyone can simply copy all code to one file to test it.
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="search-box"/>
    <div id="output-box"></div>
<script>
outputbox = document.getElementById("output-box");
inputbox  = document.getElementById("search-box");

inputbox.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    let input = inputbox.value.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (input.length) {
        fetch("/search", {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: {
              //"Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: input })
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        //.then(text => alert(text))
        .then(text => {outputbox.innerHTML = text;});
    } else {
        outputbox.innerHTML = "";
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>''')

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        #print('json:', data)
        search_term = data['searchTerm']
        results = [f'{x+1}: {search_term}' for x in range(3)]
        return render_template_string('{% for item in data %}<div>{{item}}</div>{% endfor %}', data=results)
    
    return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True 
    app.run()

